# Scientific or science-based policy-making

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

> The research centers help the government in ———— policy-making.

Scientific or science-based in the above context.

Clearly, what I mean is *policy-making that is based on science*, but does ‘scientific’ gives that meaning smoothly too?

I suspect that *scientific policy-making* might also mean *science policy-making*, that is, *policy-making for science*. Is it so? Can we thus say that ‘science-based’ is a better choice in this context?

Comment: Seems correct about the distinction. Policy-making based on scientific evidence is often called [evidence-based policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_policy).

Comment: A term that is very common in the business world is "data-driven" (https://www.atinternet.com/en/glossary/data-driven/, https://issues.org/esty-2/).  It may be a bit "jargony", and it's definitely overused, but it may also be closer to what you're trying to get at.

Comment: help the government create science policy or policies for science. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_policy

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could find in a reasonable time, but I agree with the definition given by Glenn Geher at [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/darwins-subterranean-world/201712/why-science-based-matters#:%7E:text=What%20does%20%E2%80%9Cscience%2Dbased%E2%80%9D,and%2For%20results%20into%20account) [typo corrected]:

> **What does “science-based” mean?**
>
> In the field of the behavioral sciences, where I live, we use the term
> science-based regularly. It essentially means that some decision that
> is made is done in a way that takes scientific methods and/or results
> into account. If you are going to implement some policy on some issue,
> you should make sure that scientific research on that issue strongly
> indicates that your decision is the best one.

I agree that *scientific* has too many shades of meaning to be a good choice here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *science-based* is definitely  a better term in this context, but not only because of the possible ambiguity noted in the last paragraph of the question.

*Scientific policy making* can be taken to imply that the policy will be **entirely determined** by science, that there are no other inputs into the process. It is debatable whether the conception of such policy making is even coherent (although explaining why this is so would take one outside the scope of this site), but advocating it would certainly be controversial. *Science-based policy making*, on the other hand, leaves it open that the process, while giving due weight to the results of scientific research, may also involve other aspects, such as the value judgments about the possible results of the policies. Saying that policy making ought to be science based is relatively uncontroversial.

Answer (score 1):

Although scientific and science-based seem appropriate choices, I think to provide a broader concept, the **Knowledge-based policy-making** can be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

***Scientific policy making** can be taken to imply that the policy has been determined by using the **scientific method** to consider the various factors involved.*

The [Scientific Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) can be applied to solving problems that have nothing to do with the mathematical, physical, natural or biological sciences, as the image from the cited Wikipedia page below illustrates:

[image: The scientific method]

So it is not possible to fill in the gap in the question without knowing what sort of research the centres in question are conducting. For all I know it could be in sociology, which is not what I would call a science. In that case I would use *scientific*, not science-based.

Of course, if the research centres were *in a field of science*, such as virology or epidemiology, *science-based* would be preferable, and what has been used during the recent pandemic.

Comment: I think this answer is best. Policy-making is hardly scientific per se. Though, if a government was trying to promote itself, it would probably pick the former against the latter.